# My app crashes when I call this widget and returns Lost connection to device

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-layout, flutter-test

---

I’m building an app, so far everything works. Until I click on a button that calls this Staful Widget:

```
class ToDo1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ToDo1State createState() => _ToDo1State();
}

class _ToDo1State extends State<ToDo1> {

  var User;
  late DatabaseService database;

  Future<void> connectToFirebase() async{
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    UserCredential result = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
    User = result.user;
    database = DatabaseService(User.uid);

    if (!(await database.checkIfUserExists())) {
      database.setTodo('To-Do anlegen', false);
    }
  }

  void toggleDone(String key, bool value) {
    database.setTodo(key, !value);
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
            child: Text(
          'Stufe 1',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
              decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
        )),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(35, 112, 192, 1),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: connectToFirebase(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot> (
              stream: database.getTodos(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                if(!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                } else {
                  Map<String, dynamic> items = snapshot.data!.data as Map<String, dynamic>;
                  return ListView.separated(
                      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        );
                      },
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      itemCount: items.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext, i) {
                        String key = items.keys.elementAt(i);
                        return ToDoItem(
                          key,
                          items[key]!,
                              () => toggleDone(key, items[key]),
                        );
                      });
                }
              }
            );
          }
            },
      )
    );
  }
}
```

---

Then the app crashes and the following is written in the run-console:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50673/exsIqiVEdrE=/ws
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
W/System  (16866): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(16866): Google Play Store is missing.
E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(16866): GooglePlayServices not available due to error 9
W/Firestore(16866): (23.0.3) [GrpcCallProvider]: Failed to update ssl context: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException
I/TetheringManager(16866): registerTetheringEventCallback:com.example.akne
D/FirebaseAuth(16866): Notifying id token listeners about user ( HT376N4BMNOZgX9VJ9btr6jKpce2 ).
W/om.example.akn(16866): Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (greylist-max-q,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
W/om.example.akn(16866): Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/AbstractConscryptSocket;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (greylist-max-q, reflection, denied)
E/AndroidRuntime(16866): FATAL EXCEPTION: grpc-okhttp-0
E/AndroidRuntime(16866): Process: com.example.akne, PID: 16866
E/AndroidRuntime(16866): java.lang.AssertionError: Method getAlpnSelectedProtocol not supported for object SSL socket over Socket[address=firestore.googleapis.com/142.250.184.234,port=443,localPort=60722]
E/AndroidRuntime(16866):    at io.grpc.okhttp.internal.OptionalMethod.invoke(OptionalMethod.java:114)
E/AndroidRuntime(16866):    at io.grpc.okhttp.internal.OptionalMethod.invokeWithoutCheckedException(OptionalMethod.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(16866):    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpProtocolNegotiator$AndroidNegotiator.getSelectedProtocol(OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.java:183)
E/AndroidRuntime(16866):    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpProtocolNegotiator$AndroidNegotiator.negotiate(OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.java:145)
E/AndroidRuntime(16866):    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpTlsUpgrader.upgrade(OkHttpTlsUpgrader.java:63)
E/AndroidRuntime(16866):    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$4.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:571)
E/AndroidRuntime(16866):    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(16866):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/AndroidRuntime(16866):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime(16866):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/libEGL  (16866): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
W/System  (16866): A resource failed to call close. 
W/System  (16866): A resource failed to call release. 
W/Firestore(16866): (23.0.3) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds
W/Firestore(16866): 
W/Firestore(16866): This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
W/FlutterJNI(16866): Tried to send a platform message response, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send. Response ID: 12
W/Firestore(16866): (23.0.3) [WatchStream]: (21e67d7) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Channel shutdownNow invoked, cause=null}.
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(16866): Google Play Store is missing.
E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(16866): GooglePlayServices not available due to error 9
W/Firestore(16866): (23.0.3) [GrpcCallProvider]: Failed to update ssl context: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException
W/om.example.akn(16866): Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (greylist-max-q,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
W/om.example.akn(16866): Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/AbstractConscryptSocket;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (greylist-max-q, reflection, denied)
I/Process (16866): Sending signal. PID: 16866 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

---

This is the class that interacts with the firebase:

```
class DatabaseService {
  final String userID;
  DatabaseService(this.userID);

  final CollectionReference userTodos =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userTodos');

  Future setTodo(String item, bool value) async {
    return await userTodos.doc(userID).set(
      {item:value}, SetOptions(merge: true));
  }

    Future deleteTodo(String key) async {
      return await userTodos.doc(userID).update(
        {key: FieldValue.delete(),}
      );
    }

    Future checkIfUserExists() async {
    if((await userTodos.doc(userID).get()).exists) {
      return true;
    }
      else {
        return false;
      }
    }

  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> getTodos() {
    return userTodos.doc(userID).snapshots();
  }
}
```

---

In case you need it. This is my defaultConfig in build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.akne"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

I hope I have provided all the necessary data so that the problem can be solved. If not, just write it to me and I will try to send you the material you need.

---

Comment: try removing this `await Firebase.initializeApp();` from the function `Future<void> connectToFirebase()` and adding it to the `void main()` before `runApp()`

Comment: Like this? `void main() async {await Firebase.initializeApp(); runApp(MaterialApp(home: Startseite()));}` Then it says: `LateInitializationError: Field 'database' has not been initialized.`

Comment: please share the full code

Comment: i guess the changes suggested fix the exact problem faced by you.

Comment: I think so too. It's just a new error.

Comment: You'll need to share the full code because this error has arisen due to null safety

Comment: Do you mean the full code of my app? That's a lot. But I can do it, if you want to.

Comment: yes so I may run it locally and see the issue

Comment: Is it possible for me to send you my files with the data?

Comment: if the project is on github share the link

Comment: I moved the code to Github. This is the URL: https://github.com/LarsWeber02/App/tree/master/lib      The code is located in "main.dart", "Home_Page.dart", "Stufenzusatz.dart" and "Database.dart".

Comment: Hello, are you working on it?